# Accessing Word API from an Excel add-in or vice-versa

Tags: office-js, javascript-api-for-office

In VBA, It's posssible to reference an open instance of word (using `GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")` in order to manipulate documents (`.Documents`) using the word object reference, even when the macro itself is running in excel.

Is it possible to do anything similar in office.js? I've noticed that by simply adding a `Document` host to the manifest file, an addin can be freely reconfigured to run in word or excel, with only one library (`Word` or `Excel`) loaded at a time. Executing `Word.Run` from within an excel taskpane or vice-versa will fail as the `Word` object itself is missing.

Comment: My backup plan for this one is to use `SheetJS` inside a word addin, which works quite well when I only need to read from / manipulate the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you can automate Office applications. In Office web add-ins not.